# A Party of Five

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, anagram

> AMVVUEIGURISUCOLKTAUEETS
> STTSIAOGMSEUHTLECTLH
> ADBDECAECRNEPRPIGTEAAAISLNSNCIIENONG
> EAAUAMSRFERORIICIPCEAAA
> SUBSMWIAATMLEITETETYR

> GDEEUNEXTUENERMONBOOMDSEIRUYSSS
> SPRGAAARADLUMALNGDAAASANNTLDFO
> FMWEIEOARTROAETDLH

> NRYMANPAAENEDRVTRERIINM
> FSSDCRHOAEOAPGBHGDNYYE
> TRPMHIUIIMNNDGDKBLYE
> MMBHAAAOGRRGMGIEEERT

> MLPMARAURANOCINGFZAAAANNCNOOIO
> MSHEICUUHIPGARRENROIIOENR
> NCEEAOXNSCTUGIRRENARTOIEEOVUTIESACRBNSILEIESONMENSSSS
> JCHSOLEPKUAAEBRDTERSSS

Find what's missing, then maybe you can properly locate me.

**Author note:** Partial answers or working as a team might be a good idea for this one.

Hint:

> Those "anagrams" contain multiple words which have all been meshed together. No scrambling here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to solve this puzzle is to realise that each line consists of:

> the names of **four members of a famous group of five** with their letters interleaved. The initial letters of the missing fifth names are then required for the final meta-puzzle...

The 16 lines can be resolved as follows:

AMVVUEIGURISUCOLKTAUEETS

> **A**M<sup>V</sup><sub>V</sub>**U**<sub>E</sub><sup>I</sup>**GU**<sub>R</sub>I**S**<sub>UC</sub><sup>OL</sup>K**T**<sub>A</sub>**U**E<sup>ET</sup>**S**
>
>  **AUGUSTUS**, MIKE, <sup>VIOLET</sup>, <sub>VERUCA</sub> - missing CHARLIE (Roald Dahl's prizewinning kids in *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory*)
>
>  (For readability, I will not apply similar font formatting to all the answers that follow - but hopefully this example demonstrates what the 'interleaving' of the names really means...)

STTSIAOGMSEUHTLECTLH

> SIGHT, TOUCH, TASTE, SMELL - missing HEARING (human senses)

ADBDECAECRNEPRPIGTEAAAISLNSNCIIENONG

> ACCEPTANCE, DENIAL, BARGAINING, DEPRESSION - missing ANGER (the five stages of grief)

EAAUAMSRFERORIICIPCEAAA

> EUROPE, AMERICA, ASIA, AFRICA - missing OCEANIA (continental landmasses)

SUBSMWIAATMLEITETETYR

> SWEET, UMAMI, BITTER, SALTY - missing SOUR (tastes)

GDEEUNEXTUENERMONBOOMDSEIRUYSSS

> GENESIS, DEUTERONOMY, EXODUS, NUMBERS - missing LEVITICUS (books of the Pentateuch)

SPRGAAARADLUMALNGDAAASANNTLDFO

> SARUMAN, PALLANDO, RADAGAST, GANDALF - missing ALATAR ([LotR wizards](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Wizards))

FMWEIEOARTROAETDLH

> FIRE, METAL, WOOD, EARTH - missing WATER ([Wuxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuxing_(Chinese_philosophy)) - the five Chinese elements)

NRYMANPAAENEDRVTRERIINM

> NYNAEVE, RAND, MATRIM, PERRIN - missing EGWENE (five main characters from *[The Wheel of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time)*)

FSSDCRHOAEOAPGBHGDNYYE

> FRED, SCOOBY, SHAGGY, DAPHNE - missing VELMA ([Mystery Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo) gang)

TRPMHIUIIMNNDGDKBLYE

> THUMB, RING, PINKY, MIDDLE - missing INDEX (digits of the hand)

MMBHAAAOGRRGMGIEEERT

> MAGGIE, MARGE, BART, HOMER - missing LISA (*The Simpsons*)

MLPMARAURANOCINGFZAAAANNCNOOIO

> MARANZANO, LUCIANO, PROFACI, MANGANO - missing GAGLIANO ([the Five Families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Families))

MSHEICUUHIPGARRENROIIOENR

> MICHIGAN, SUPERIOR, HURON, ERIE - missing ONTARIO (Great Lakes)

NCEEAOXNSCTUGIRRENARTOIEEOVUTIESACRBNSILEIESONMENSSSS

> NEUROTICISM, CONSCIENTIOUSNESS, EXTRAVERSION, AGREEABLENESS - missing OPENNESS TO EXPERIENCE (personality traits)

JCHSOLEPKUAAEBRDTERSSS

> JOKER, CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES - missing DIAMONDS (playing cards)

Finally then...

> The initial letters of these missing members spell out **CHAOS**, **LAW**, **EVIL** and **GOOD**. I believe these are all connected via [alignments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) in *Dungeons & Dragons* and that the fifth option missing from this particular group is therefore **NEUTRAL**. This would fit with the title too, since a 'party of five' is pretty much the ideal number of players you want in order to play the game!

Comment: Good job! As for the missing one... (Znlor n 6-svther erc zrzore pna uryc lbh bhg... :)  )

Comment: @Auribouros Aha, in which case I know what it is!

Comment: And a little added flavor, (Gur dhrfgvba nfxf gb svaq jurer V nz, naq zl FR cebsvyr vf "ybpngrq" ba gur puneg vgfrys!) Congrats!